# Nested if structure in c not working the way expected

Tags: c

I am a beginning programmer who has made little number-guessing code here as an exercise. The c code here does not print "Correct!" if a user guesses the right number. Why is this nested if structure not working?
**strong text**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int iRandomNum = 0;
    char cUserInput = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));
    iRandomNum = (rand() % 10) + 1;

    printf("Guess a number between 1 to 10:");
    scanf("%c", &cUserInput);

    if(isdigit(cUserInput))
    {
        if(cUserInput==iRandomNum)
          printf ("Correct!");
        else
          printf("The right answer was %d", iRandomNum);
    }
    else
      printf("You did not enter a digit.");

      return 0;

}
```

Comment: It's hard to enter `10` in a single character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`char` is used for characters, so if you enter 5 then `scanf` will assign character '5' to variable `cUserInput`. If C implementation uses ASCII coding for characters then '5' is equal to number 53 which will never be equal to `iRandomNum`.

Solution is to use `int` if you want numbers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int iRandomNum = 0;
    int cUserInput = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));
    iRandomNum = (rand() % 10) + 1;

    printf("Guess a number between 1 to 10:");
    scanf("%d", &cUserInput);

    if(cUserInput>=1 && cUserInput<=10)
    {
        if(cUserInput==iRandomNum)
          printf ("Correct!");
        else
          printf("The right answer was %d", iRandomNum);
    }
    else
      printf("You did not enter a digit.");

      return 0;

}
```

Comment: For some reason using int is not working either; try it yourself. Just tell if you have a solution, I hope you've got the basic idea of what I am trying to do.

Comment: @ShubhRoy Sorry, I did forgot to mention that `isDigit` stops working, because `cUserInput` is no longer a character. Edited my answer.

Comment: What to do if you want to verify if it is a digit?

Comment: @ShubhRoy It's not digit, it's a number. The `if` statement just checks that it's between 1 and 10. `iRandom` can be 10, that's not a digit either.